# How do I activate an Excel worksheet that has a date label

Tags: vba, excel

favorite
My current macro pulls in multiple workbooks bringing in roughly 100 worksheets. The macro then filters and pulls in the data from 10 or 11 specific worksheets to create a new sheet with the data I need. Each of the 100 sheets has fairly unique names from "DataFX GL Data" to "SAP_ALL_175031".

There is one file I am having a hard time selecting. It is labeled with a date. Each month a new sheet is added with a day and month ("30 November" for example). I am new to vba and am not certain where to begin so I only have an example of another sheet that I am selecting. How can I select the worksheet labeled with the most recent date?

```
Dim Deleterow As Long, EndRow As Long 
Dim lRow As Variant 
Dim rngRow As Range 
Dim rngSelection As Range 

Set rngSelection = Range("A1").CurrentRegion

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    With ws
        If Left(ws.Name, 7) = "Sheet 1" Then
            EndRow = LastRow(ws)

            For Deleterow = EndRow To 2 Step -1

                If .Cells(Deleterow, 9) = .Cells(Deleterow, 12) Then
                    .Rows(Deleterow).EntireRow.Delete
                End If
            Next Deleterow
        End If
```

[image]

Comment: *labeled with the most recent date* - is there some logic that will determine what the most recent date is each time you run the code? like always end of previous month or something like that?

Comment: Do you have overlapping years in the same workbook?  If so, how do you tell which Day-Month worksheet is the latest?

Comment: The years don't overlap. Each year the file starts fresh.  Scott is correct. The date labels are generally the last day of the previous month.  I will add an example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `EOMonth` WorksheetFunction inside the VBA code to determine the last day of the previous month:

```
Dim lastMonth As Date

lastMonth = WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(Date, -1)
Debug.Print lastMonth
Debug.Print Format(lastMonth, "dd mmmm")
```

Results:

> 12/31/2017
>   31 December

Then

```
If ws.Name = Format(lastMonth, "dd mmmm") Then
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the name of the worksheet with the latest date, given the constraint that all of the dates are within the same year, you can do something like the following:

```
Option Explicit
Sub LatestWorksheet()
    Dim WB As Workbook, WS As Worksheet
    Dim wsName As String

Set WB = ThisWorkbook
For Each WS In WB.Worksheets
    If IsDate(WS.Name) Then
        If wsName = "" Then
            wsName = WS.Name
        ElseIf DateValue(WS.Name & " 2012") > DateValue(wsName & " 2012") Then _
            wsName = WS.Name
        End If
    End If
Next WS

Debug.Print wsName

End Sub
```

Note that I fixed the year to 2012 in order to allow for `29 Feb`.  Otherwise it would alter the proper order.  Given the date/string, VBA would assume the current year.  If the file year were a leap year, and the current year was not, `29 Feb` would get converted in an undesired manner by the `DateValue` function.

Comment: Couldn't you just focus on the month?  Are there multiple sheets with the same month?

Comment: @mooseman There are any number of methods to solve this problem which will work. Some require more assumptions than others on the structure of the workbook. Some require more complex coding.  My assumption was that the worksheet name looked like a date in `DM` type of format, and that all of the worksheets would have been generated for the same year (Jan to Dec). If you make other assumptions, you may be able to produce different code that will work as well or better. Post your answer with your assumptions and code.

Comment: @mooseman You could also assume that the sheets are ordered in such a way so that all you'd have to do is loop backwards from the last sheet to the first that has a `DM` format.  Seems to me that might not be as robust a solution.

Comment: The asker did say there is only 1 year and that each month a new sheet is added.  I don't believe I made any assumptions.  Just a simple question.

Comment: As I wrote above *There are any number of methods to solve this problem which will work*. And focusing just on the months is another method. But you are getting into opinions here, which is off-topic for SO. And since you have not presented your code, I cannot really comment on your approach. But I feel mine might be more robust, and will handle more potential user errors and/or misstatements in the original question. MIne might be easier to code, but without seeing your approach, hard to say for sure.